# Sql Server datetime conversion

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to convert varchar date value to datetime format. Showing error

select CONVERT(DATETIME, Convert(varchar, 20/12/2009, 103 ),103)

error: Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

Geetha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the string otherwise it treats it as an expression and tries to do the divisions:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, Convert(varchar, '20/12/2009', 103 ),103)
```

Although having said that only one Convert is really necessary so you can use

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '20/12/2009',103)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, '20/12/2009', 103)
```

Not sure what your conversion TO varchar is for...

Answer (score 0):

I would say you at least have to add quotes arround the string representing the date :

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, Convert(varchar, '20/12/2009', 103 ),103)
```

*(Maybe there's another problem too : I don't have an SQL Server instance available, so I cannot test)*

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the date string:

```
select CONVERT(DATETIME, Convert(varchar, '20/12/2009', 103 ),103)
```

And you don't need two converts. This is should be enough:

```
select Convert(varchar, '20/12/2009', 103 )
```